# Selenium Webdriver unable to get elements in Modal

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I am writing a Selenium Webdriver script that is supposed to click on a Link and then this Modal Window pops up.

[image: Modal Window on the page]

When I try to access card number field (//input[@id=pan]), I get No such element found exception `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"pan"}`

[image: Input control I want to get hold of]

This is the code I have tried with no luck:

```
WebElement modal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ute-pay-now-modalContent']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(modal);
WebElement el =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pan']"));
```

Also tried this:

```
WebElement modal = driver.findElement(By.className("ute-pay-now-modalContent"));
driver.switchTo().frame(modal);
WebElement el =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pan']"));
```

Also tried this:

```
WebDriverWait block = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
WebElement modal = block.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("ute-pay-now-modalContent")));
WebElement pan;
pan    = modal.findElement(By.id("pan"));
```

Also tried this:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Also tried this:

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

Can someone please help suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You've defined `modal` variable, but trying to switch to `model` (`"modEl" != "modAl"`). Also note that `div` with `ute-pay-now-modalContent` class name is not an `iframe`, so you shouldn't use `switchTo().frame()`. Share page `URL` if possible

Comment: @Andersson: I have corrected the typo. If I can't use Frame because it is Modal, then how do I get input fields from the Modal? I haven't have the luck yet. It is a very common scenario that Selenium might be handling already in someway that I can't find out.

Comment: Can you share page `URL`?

Comment: @Andersson: Not sure how would it help because the page I am talking about is secure and needs login (unable to share my credential). But here you go: https://www.rogers.com/web/totes/#/signin

Comment: Share exception you get with `modal = block.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("ute-pay-now-modalContent"))); modal.findElement(By.id("pan"));`

Comment: `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"pan"}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seem that `<div class="ute-pay-‌​now-modalContent">` contains `iframe#sema` with required `input` field. Try below code and let me know the result:

```
WebDriverWait block = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
block.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("ute-pay-now-modalContent")));
driver.switchTo().frame("sema");
WebElement pan;
pan = modal.findElement(By.id("pan"));
```

Comment: Interesting. This seems to be working in getting me the "pan" element! How do you find out about "sema" frame? Because I am getting same issue for other elements on the same modal. Do I need to switch frame before getting each element, or I should be able to get all elements in Modal after one time switch.

Comment: You can check that `input` is descendant of `<iframe id="sema">`. This is embedded `HTML` document. To handle elements inside `iframe` you have to switch to it first. If after handling `input` you need to handle other elements outside `iframe` you should switch back to main document `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`.

Comment: ahhh, Nice! Learned something new. Thank you @Anderson

Comment: [Obsolete("The ExpectedConditions implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)")][Obsolete("The ExpectedConditions implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)")]

Comment: Because ExpectedConditions is marked as obsolete and that it is being moved to another library, I had to find another long-term solution.

Instead of trying to access the modal, I simply used Driver.Navigate.GoToUrl(...) to navigate directly to the content.

Using Driver.Navigate.Back() returned me back to the previous content; however, it may be necessary to perform multiple back calls.